# Whirr for large cluster beyond 10 Nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2

Whenever I try to fire up clusters larger than 10 nodes using whirr -0.8.2 The cluster fails to initialize.Is it a problem of 0.8.2 . In Jira it has been posed it was resolved in latest trunk .

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to fix this. I built whirr from the trunk (version 0.9.0). And then added the following parameters to increase the timeout period.

```
jclouds.compute.timeout.node-terminated=2200000
jclouds.compute.timeout.node-running=2600000
jclouds.compute.timeout.script-complete=22000000
jclouds.compute.timeout.port-open=2200000 jclouds.ssh.retry-auth=true
jclouds.compute.poll-status.initial-period=20000
jclouds.compute.poll-status.max-period=20000
```

Apart from this also added:

```
whirr.instance-templates-max-percent-failures=100
hadoop-namenode+yarn-resourcemanager+mapreduce-historyserver,80
hadoop-datanode+hadoop-tasktracker
whirr.terminate-all-on-launch-failure=true
```

And now whir is able to start up large clusters.